# Как лучше сохранять картинки?

Tags: c#, asp.net, изображения, entity-framework, angular

Я использую ASP.NET Core и Entity Framework (на фронтэнде использую Angular 8). Создаю сайт на котором нужно хранить много картинок, так же загружать их и просматривать. Как лучше сохранять картинки: в базе даных, или в папке на сервере и названия в бд? Какие плюсы и минусы в каждном из вариантов?
Так же какие действия с картинкой желатильно сделать, для оптимизации памяти? Какие библиотеки лучше использовать?

Comment: Так это все от ваших задач и требований зависит. Например, вы бекапить собираетесь сайт? Вы данные одним бекапом бд хотите иметь или бд отдельно, файлы отдельно? Вы картинки свои планируете пережимать? Или в оригинале хранить? Вот у меня 300 гигов фоток - такое не каждая бд вывезет

Comment: @tym32167 Бекапы делать буду выходя из того, каким способом картинки сохранять буду. А все остальные ваши вопросы - уже задал я.

Comment: лучше хранить отдельно, а в бд хранить лишь название / путь.